# Prove by using strong induction that for any n ≥ 3, any way to fully parenthesize A1 ∪ A2 ∪ · · · ∪ An gives the same set.

Tags: logic, induction

I have no idea where to start on this.

I assume the base case is when n=3, which is proved by the rule of commutativity. But I do not know where to go from there.

A fully parenthesized formula is defined recursively as: A∪B, (α)∪(β), A∪(β), (α)∪B,
where α and β are any fully parenthesize formula, A and B are any set. You can use the following
equivalence on formula:(A∪B)∪C = A∪(B ∪C),(A∪(α))∪C = A∪((α)∪C),((β)∪B)∪C =(β)∪(B∪C),((α)∪(β))∪C = (α)∪((β)∪C), where α and β are any fully parenthesize formula,
A and B are any set.

Comment: I think you don't want commutativity but *associativity*

Comment: Besides, could you please provide a more precise definition of "fully parenthesize"?

Comment: just added the definition